# Javascript $.trim but not spaces: underline / underscore

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a mask with *_*_ as placeholder. But I need to `$.trim` this. Does someone know how?

Thank you!

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: $.trim only removes trailing/following whitespace ?

Comment: `string.replace('__','');`

Comment: over php its so easy, only this:

$text = str_replace('_', '', $text);

But javascript... omg, its so hard. Why we need to use this?

Comment: @FcbInfo - seriously! The syntax is almost identical in javascript. Both languages are C-like ?

Comment: Sorry adeneo, I just don't know nothing of javascrit. I'm learning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
function trimUnderscores(string) {
    regex = new RegExp('_+([^_]*)_+', '')
    return string.replace(regex, '$1')
}

string = trimUnderscores("___ ddjfjhd ____")

alert(string)
```

It is using the **[replace method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)** with **[regex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)**.

Comment: Well, that work like a monster. But if i need to write this code i cant. JavaScript is so hard. I Love php. LOL! Anyway, thank you... and +1 for you!

Comment: If my answer could help you, you can validate it...

Comment: Validated =)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No need for jquery, simple regex replace:

```
alert("__some string & stuff _".replace(/^_+|_+$/g,""));
```

Comment: I have this:
if($.trim($("#field").val()) != "")

Comment: So.... make it `if($("#field").val().replace(/^_+|_+$/g,"")!="")`